# Groovy DSL: How can I let two delegating classes handle different parts of a DSLScript?

Tags: groovy, dsl

Let's say I have a DSL like this

```
setup {name = "aDSLScript"}
println "this is common groovy code"
doStuff {println "I'm doing dsl stuff"}
```

One would have a delegating class implementing the methods 'setup' and 'doStuff' usually. Beside, one could write common Groovy code to be executed (println...).

What I am searching for, is a way to execute this in two steps. In the first step only the setup method should be processed (neither println). The second step handles the other parts.

At the moment, I have two delegating classes. One implements 'setup' the other one implements 'doStuff'. But both execute the println statement, of course.

Comment: Some code would help a lot to know what you are trying.

Comment: There's not much more code than what you see above. To interpret the DSL script above, I got to classes: SetupProcessor which implements a method setup. CoreProcessor which implements doStuff. The script is executed 2 times. First time, I set the delegate of the parsed script (Script.class) to SetupProcessor. Second time, I set the delegate to CoreProcessor:  `def cc = new CompilerConfiguration()`  `def core = new CoreProcessor()`  
`cc.scriptBaseClass = DelegatingScript.class.name`  `def script = sh.parse(dslscript)`  
`script.setDelegate(core)`  
`script.run()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to split up execution of the DSL script. I used a [`CompilationCustomizer`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/customizers/CompilationCustomizer.html) to remove every statement from AST except the `doFirst{}`. So the first run will only execute `doFirst`. The second run does everything else. Here's some code:

```
class DoFirstProcessor {
    def doFirst(Closure c) {
        c()
    }
}

class TheRestProcessor {
    def doStuff(Closure c) {
        c()
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        //nothing to do
    }
}

def dsl = "
println 'this is text that will not be printed out in first line!'

doFirst { println 'First things first: e.g. setting up environment' }

doStuff { println 'doing some stuff now' }

println 'That is it!'
"


class HighlanderCustomizer extends CompilationCustomizer {
    def methodName

    HighlanderCustomizer(def methodName) {
        super(CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
        this.methodName = methodName
    }

    @Override
    void call(SourceUnit sourceUnit, GeneratorContext generatorContext, ClassNode classNode) throws CompilationFailedException {
        def methods = classNode.getMethods()
        methods.each { MethodNode m ->
            m.code.each { Statement st ->
                if (!(st instanceof BlockStatement)) {
                    return
                }
                def removeStmts = []
                st.statements.each { Statement bst ->
                    if (bst instanceof ExpressionStatement) {
                        def ex = bst.expression
                        if (ex instanceof MethodCallExpression) {
                            if (!ex.methodAsString.equals(methodName)) {
                                removeStmts << bst
                            }
                        } else {
                            removeStmts << bst
                        }
                    } else {
                        removeStmts << bst
                    }
                }
                st.statements.removeAll(removeStmts)
            }
        }
    }
}

def cc = new CompilerConfiguration()
cc.addCompilationCustomizers new HighlanderCustomizer("doFirst")
cc.scriptBaseClass = DelegatingScript.class.name

def doFirstShell = new GroovyShell(new Binding(), cc)
def doFirstScript = doFirstShell.parse dsl
doFirstScript.setDelegate new DoFirstProcessor()
doFirstScript.run()

cc.compilationCustomizers.clear()
def shell = new GroovyShell(new Binding(), cc)
def script = shell.parse dsl
script.setDelegate new TheRestProcessor()
script.run()
```

I did another variation of this where I execute the DSL in one step. See my blog post about it: http://hackserei.metacode.de/?p=247

Comment: Very clever solution with `CompilationCustomizer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single class to intercept the method calls from the script and let it coordinate the following method invoke. I did it through reflection, but you can go declarative if you want. These are the model and script classes:

```
class FirstDelegate {
  def setup(closure) { "firstDelegate.setup" }
}

class SecondDelegate {
  def doStuff(closure) { "secondDelegate.doStuff" }
}


class MethodInterceptor {
  def invokedMethods = []

  def methodMissing(String method, args) {
    invokedMethods << [method: method, args: args]
  }

  def delegate() {
    def lookupCalls = { instance ->
      def invokes = instance.metaClass.methods.findResults { method ->
        invokedMethods.findResult { invocation ->
          invocation.method == method.name ? 
              [method: method, invocation: invocation] : null 
        }
      }

      invokes.collect { invoked ->
        invoked.method.invoke(instance, invoked.invocation.args) 
      }
    }

    return lookupCalls(new FirstDelegate()) + lookupCalls(new SecondDelegate())
  }
}
```

Here be scripts and assertions:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

def dsl = '''
setup {name = "aDSLScript"}
println "this is common groovy code"
doStuff {println "Ima doing dsl stuff"}
'''


def compiler = new CompilerConfiguration()
compiler.scriptBaseClass = DelegatingScript.class.name

def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), compiler)

script = shell.parse dsl

interceptor = new MethodInterceptor()

script.setDelegate interceptor

script.run()

assert interceptor.invokedMethods*.method == [ 'setup', 'doStuff' ]

assert interceptor.delegate() == 
    ['firstDelegate.setup', 'secondDelegate.doStuff']
```

---

Notice I didn't bothered intercepting `println` call, which is a `DefaultGroovyMethods` thus, a little more cumbersome to handle.

Also having the class `MethodInterceptor` implementing the method `delegate()` is not a good idea, since this allows the user-defined script to call it.

Comment: Thank you! This is a good way how to group DSL function implementations over different classes. But sadly it doesn't fix my problem. I want to run the script twice. The first run is to do a setup (e.g. environment stuff). The second run (sometimes later) should do the actual work. This is why it's important to me that println is not interpretet by the SetupProcessor class.

Comment: Well, I first didn't get the part with controlling the next method invoke. But there's still the problem with println or other groovy methods. Isn't there a way to avoid every method invokation except 'setup'?